# Big O Notation Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime, big-o

Is the worst case run time for the function below O(n^2)? Because the while loop is O(n) and the body has lst[1:] which is O(n) so O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2)?

```
def fn(lst):
    ans = 0
    while lst != []:
        ans = ans + lst[0]
        lst = lst[1:]
    return ans > 100
```

Comment: Yes, `slice` is `O(k)` but your `k` is `n-1` so you can use `n`.

Comment: Why is `lst[1:]` `O(n)`?

Comment: Times are provided: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list

Comment: It is of course trivial to make this `O(n)` vs `O(n^2)`, so I assume the example is contrived.

Comment: Not just worst case, but average case as well!

Comment: @AChampion what if I have  list(map(fn)) and fn was O(n) would this apply the same idea as the loop so this would also be and example of O(n^2)?

Comment: Yes, of course `n*n = O(n^2)`